# How to disable submit button which caused post back on ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel inside page with couple of buttons. Each button cause PostBack event. But I found that user can click multiple times in button and crash application. I want ot disable all buttons on first click until postback will be handled and new content of UpdatePanel arrived.

I tried to bind (via jquery) to 'click' event of button, set 'disabled; attribute and call 'submit' on parent form. Unfortunately is seems that this method not working - content of UpdatePanel still old.

After that I tried to override 'submit' event but faced another issue - how to submit form again if I came to my handler each time? It may be fixed with introducing flag variable, but I dislike it - another variable just increase code entropy.

Maybe I can do it somehow with ASP.NET methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply ajax UpdateProgress and put your code in UpdatePanel as to disable Button after first click:

```
<aspAtlas:UpdateProgress ID="upUpdatePanelProgress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0"
            DynamicLayout="true" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updpnlProgram">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="overlay" runat="server">
                        <img runat="server" id="img1" src="../Images/UpdateProgress.gif" alt="Loading..." /><br />
                        <br />
                        <b>Loading...</b>
                    </asp:Panel>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </aspAtlas:UpdateProgress>
 <aspAtlas:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updpnlProgram" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
<div>
//--Your code in this div
</div>
 </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <aspAtlas:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button_ID" />
        </Triggers>
    </aspAtlas:UpdatePanel>
```